# JLoader for JLog

Tags: joomla-3.x, error-handling, logs

I'm currently using the following to load `JLog`:

```
jimport('joomla.log.log');
```

I'd like to make use of `JLoader`, however I'm unsure as to which file I need to register. Would I use:

```
JLoader::register('JLog', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/log/log.php');
```

or:

```
JLoader::register('JLogger', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/log/logger.php');
```

or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need only this:

```
JLoader::register('JLog', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/log/log.php');
```

This is the main class for logging.